# Fetching unread page conversation using Graph API and/or FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I fetch page conversations with unread messages only using either Graph API or FQL ?

I did not found any table reference for that in FQL and in Graph API I can't figure out if I can filter unread messages only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it this way.

```
SELECT sender, body FROM unified_message 
WHERE thread_id IN 
     (SELECT thread_id FROM unified_thread WHERE folder = 'inbox' AND unread=1) 
 AND unread=1 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

for more information: [How to get unread messages using FQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016843/how-to-get-unread-messages-using-fql/25250051#25250051)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/unified_message):

The `unread` parameter is not indexed, and thus cannot be searched. You'll havta get all the messages, and filter them yourself.

Comment: This is FQL, what about Graph API ?

Comment: There does not seem to be a way to do this via a single endpoint or parameter combination. I've never understood why people insist on the "graph api" over FQL. FQL is a method of the Graph API.

Comment: I do not insist i will do that with whatever API available. But it seems there isn't any

Answer (score 0):

this is the fql for view unread conversation:

```
SELECT message_id, author_id, body, created_time, viewer_id, thread_id FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0 and unread != 0)
```